# Why the children of the relative node doesn't delete when i click on the button?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on my homework. I need to delete "ol" from the list using a button with javascript.

I've tried to using a div for all the children and a div for each but doesn't seem to work.

There's my script:

```
window.onload = function() {
    const parent = document.querySelector('ul');
}
function supprime() {
    parent.removeChild(parent.lastElementChild);
}
```

and my html...

```html
<ul>
    <ol>Item</ol>
    <ol>Item</ol>
    <ol>Item</ol>
    <ol>Item</ol>
</ul>
<button onclick='supprime()'>DELETE</button>
```

The console log doesn't show any error.

Comment: ["What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `parent` is declared with `const`, it is scoped to the anonymous function attached to `onload`. In the context of the `supprime` function, `typeof parent === 'undefined'`.

One fix would be to move the declaration of `parent` outside the two functions and make it variable with `let`. (See James' answer.)

Another fix would be to move `const parent = document.querySelector('ul')` inside `supprime`.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // This `parent` won't be used in `supprime`, because `const` scopes it to this function.
  const parent = 'nothing';
}

function supprime() {
  const parent = document.querySelector('ul');
  parent.removeChild(parent.lastElementChild);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <ol>Item</ol>
    <ol>Item</ol>
    <ol>Item</ol>
    <ol>Item</ol>
</ul>
<button onclick='supprime()'>DELETE</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a variable inside the function `function() { const parent = document.querySelector('ul'); }` and then throwing it away - this variable is out of scope to the function `supprime()`. Read up on scopes.

This modification of your code will work - declare the variable in a place both functions can access it and just modify it when `window.onload` is called:

```js
let parent;

window.onload = function() {
    parent = document.querySelector('ul');
}
function supprime() {
    parent.removeChild(parent.lastElementChild);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <ol>Item</ol>
    <ol>Item</ol>
    <ol>Item</ol>
    <ol>Item</ol>
</ul>
<button onclick='supprime()'>DELETE</button>
```

Though you still need to handle when the list is empty, otherwise your button function will throw an error. Something like this would get around that:

```js
function supprime() {
    if(parent.children.length !== 0) {
        parent.removeChild(parent.lastElementChild);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or as [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58082577/8230810) states, you don't need to declare the `parent` variable onload at all. Unless this is a simplified version of your actual use-case, where you do need to declare stuff like that onload.